# How to disable the source map in production build in Nuxt 2

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

In my website source codes of two source maps are exposed:
-static/vendor/adminlte/js/adminlte.min.js
-static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js

As i have understood, in Vue.js it is completed by

`productionSourceMap: false,`

But how I can hide the source codes in Nuxt 2?

Comment: First of, why do you want to hide this? Having `static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js` is not an issue in any way. At the end, you're shipping your code to the frontend and it doesn't really matter that you're loading BS or where it is located. Also, here there is nothing related to source maps directly because the files you shared are not hashed + are located in `static` (for some reason). Please edit your question with the actual issue you're facing + what you want to achieve. PS: there is no need to obfuscate anything tho, keep the Web performant and clean please.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can set `devtools: false` inside your config:

```js
export default {
  vue: {
    config: {
      productionTip: true,
      devtools: false
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-vue-config
}

Comment: This one is already `false` by default: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#devtools